# PowerBuilder Script to set ARITHABORT ON/OFF

Tags: powerbuilder, arithabort

How to set ARITHABORT (SessionProperty in SQL server) in PowerBuilder script?
While opening an application (which is created in PB) I want to set ARITHABORT ON/OFF.

Please help...With your answers

Comment: Sounds like something you would put in the dbparm of the connection.

Comment: Can u give me any example please...

Comment: SQLCA.dbParm = "PacketSize = 2048"

Comment: It doesn't help as i am beginner in PowerBuilder can u give any proper script. @matt-balent

Comment: It doesn't help as i am beginner in PowerBuilder can u give any proper script.@https://stackoverflow.com/users/1506715/matt-balent